# How to get the full page url using php (without page name and parameters)

Tags: php

I am running a page with url like this `http://www.domain.com/test/reports/index.php`

I need to get the url using php with out index.php like

```
http://www.domain.com/test/reports/
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php):

```
$url = (($_SERVER['HTTPS']=="on")?"https://":"http://").$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URL'];
$parts = parse_url($url);
$urlpath = $parts['scheme']."://".$parts['host'].$parts['path'];
```

Comment: I need to get the page url using php itself

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.domain.com/test/reports/index.php';
$file_name = basename($url);
echo str_replace($file_name, '', $url);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To be thorough, you'll want to start with [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

```
$parts=parse_url("http://domain.com/user/100");
```

That will give you an array with a handful of keys.  The one you are looking for is `path`.

Split the path on `/` and take the last one.

```
$path_parts=explode('/', $parts['path']);
```

Your ID is now in `$path_parts[count($path_parts)-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

a noob way to do this with explode implode

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.domain.com/test/reports/index.php";
$newurl = explode("/", $url);
array_pop($newurl);
implode("/",$newurl);
?>
```

Comment: What makes this a noob way? how could this be improved to make it not noob code?